# How to read specific columns from CSV in R and write results to file row-wise?

Tags: r, csv

We have a CSV file in this format:

```
id1, id2, id3, id4, id5
23,24,23,25,23
25,46,23,756,34
23,54,73,83,74
...
```

We have an R script ready that reads data, processes it (makes forecasts and predictions) pertaining to each column and then writes result onto file. Problem is, currently it expects only 1 column / id in a CSV. We have recently introduced multiple columns in the CSV (as shown above). We want the script to read each column, process it, and then store predictions in the output CSV and then do the same for other columns. Our script is:

```
library("forecast")
data = read.csv("data.csv")
seasonal_per <- msts(data,seasonal.periods=c(24,168))
best_model <- tbats(seasonal_per)
fcst <- forecast.tbats(best_model,h=24,level=90)
dfForec <- print(fcst)
result <- cbind(0:23,dfForec[, 1])
write.csv(result, file="out.csv")
```

The resulting 'out.csv' contains:

```
"","V1","V2"
"1",0,5080.64143403622
"2",1,5024.80341301731
"3",2,4697.62476220884
"4",3,4419.10506083084
"5",4,4262.78237536907
"6",5,4187.62903442766
"7",6,4349.19557668607
"8",7,4484.10807151227
"9",8,4247.8575479654
"10",9,3851.37930582024
"11",10,3575.95149262212
"12",11,3494.94340348126
"13",12,3501.35397669752
"14",13,3445.56274629188
"15",14,3362.23686727733
"16",15,3365.56431618894
"17",16,3573.96314478735
"18",17,3945.43879134651
"19",18,4278.44501871782
"20",19,4499.11200729996
"21",20,4574.2023320236
"22",21,4555.22528793877
"23",22,4550.89877322609
"24",23,4517.26727161547
```

(which are 24 predictions based on 1 id)

The new script will read each column 1 by 1 (without referencing hard-coded column names), process, predict, and then store results in this format:

```
"id","V1","V2"
"id1",0,5080.64143403622
"id1",1,5024.80341301731
"id1",2,4697.62476220884
"id1",3,4419.10506083084
"id1",4,4262.78237536907
"id1",5,4187.62903442766
"id1",6,4349.19557668607
"id1",7,4484.10807151227
"id1",8,4247.8575479654
"id1",9,3851.37930582024
"id1",10,3575.95149262212
"id1",11,3494.94340348126
"id1",12,3501.35397669752
"id1",13,3445.56274629188
"id1",14,3362.23686727733
"id1",15,3365.56431618894
"id1",16,3573.96314478735
"id1",17,3945.43879134651
"id1",18,4278.44501871782
"id1",19,4499.11200729996
"id1",20,4574.2023320236
"id1",21,4555.22528793877
"id1",22,4550.89877322609
"id1",23,4517.26727161547
"id2",0,5080.64143403622    <-- id2 predictions begin
"id2",1,5024.80341301731    <-- id2 predictions begin
```

**UPDATE:** Tried the code as suggested by @Parfait but it gives the following error:

```
Error in file(file, ifelse(append, "a", "w")) : 
  cannot open the connection
In addition: There were 26 warnings (use warnings() to see them)
```

Also, the finaldf dataframe is empty:

```
> finaldf
      <NA> V1 V2
 [1,] NULL 0  1 
 [2,] NULL 0  1 
 [3,] NULL 0  1 
 [4,] NULL 0  1 
 [5,] NULL 0  1 
 [6,] NULL 0  1 
 [7,] NULL 0  1 
 [8,] NULL 0  1 
 [9,] NULL 0  1 
[10,] NULL 0  1 
[11,] NULL 0  1 
[12,] NULL 0  1 
[13,] NULL 0  1 
[14,] NULL 0  1 
[15,] NULL 0  1 
[16,] NULL 0  1 
[17,] NULL 0  1 
[18,] NULL 0  1 
[19,] NULL 0  1 
[20,] NULL 0  1 
[21,] NULL 0  1 
[22,] NULL 0  1 
[23,] NULL 0  1 
[24,] NULL 0  1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an approach using `lapply` and `ldply` from the `plyr` package:

```
# Make replicable example with fake data and function
d <- as.data.frame(replicate(5, rnorm(100)))
names(d) <- paste0("id", 1:5)
get_numbers <- function(x) {
  data.frame(V1 = 1:10, V2 = sample(x, 10))
}

out <- lapply(d, get_numbers)
out <- plyr::ldply(out)
out    
#    .id V1           V2
# 1  id1  1 -0.462111424
# 2  id1  2  0.431549655
# 3  id1  3  1.360865990
# ..snip..
# 9  id1  9 -0.110209805
# 10 id1 10 -0.335578166
# 11 id2  1 -0.246840243
# 12 id2  2 -0.881482663
# 13 id2  3  0.352842837
# ..snip..
```

To modify this example for your task, you may want to wrap your processing steps into a function, e.g.

```
process <- function(x) {
  seasonal_per <- msts(x, seasonal.periods=c(24,168))
  best_model <- tbats(seasonal_per)
  fcst <- forecast.tbats(best_model,h=24,level=90)
  dfForec <- print(fcst)
  result <- cbind(0:23, dfForec[, 1])
}
```

and then do, e.g. `lapply(d, process)`.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using `lapply()` with `seq_along()` to retrieve number indexing of each column. Such an index will be used to retrieve *data* and *name* of column. Together, this will produce a list of dataframes of prediction values. Once iteration is complete, then run a `do.call()` to stack the list's individual dataframes:

```
data <- read.csv("data.csv")
data[is.na(data)] <- 0

dfList <- lapply(seq_along(data), function(i) {
    seasonal_per <- msts(data[, i], seasonal.periods=c(24,168))
    best_model <- tbats(seasonal_per)
    fcst <- forecast.tbats(best_model, h=24, level=90)
    dfForec <- print(fcst)
    result <- cbind(0:23, dfForec[, 1])
    result$id <- names(data)[i]
    names(result)[1:2] <- c("V1", "V2")

    return(result[c("id", "V1", "V2")])
})

finaldf <- do.call(rbind, dfList)
write.csv(finaldf, file = "out.csv", row.names = FALSE)
```

Comment: Missing values in the CSV are causing the script to break. Could you please modify the example above so that it assumes a '0' when a missing value is encountered in the CSV?

Comment: Try adding just after reading in csv: `data[is.na(data)] <- 0`

Comment: I tried that it gives the following error: `Error in data[is.na(data)] <- 0 : 
  object of type 'closure' is not subsettable
In addition: Warning message:
In is.na(data) : is.na() applied to non-(list or vector) of type 'closure'`

Comment: Is your dataframe named **data**? This errs on incorrect df name.

Comment: I corrected the `data` error and now I find that the out.csv is created but doesn't have the required predictions output. It just contains 'V1, V2, V3' and `NULL NULL NULL` in the next row. The script executes without error though. Any ideas?

Comment: The script does generate the required predictions correctly because I can see them rolling up on screen while the script is computing. However, the error is in writing them to file. Could you please take a look at logic to output predictions to 'out.csv'?

Comment: See update with explicit naming of columns. And the `result$id` previously used wrong df reference. Also, check `finaldf` object. Is it an empty dataframe?

Comment: I updated the question to include the error I am getting after trying your code. The final write to CSV has some error and `finaldf` seems to contain all `NULL`. Please see update to question.

Comment: Recall you did not use the correct dataframe name, **data** in first error above. Did you replace **data** with the actual df name inside the lapply function, specifically with lines: `seasonal_per <- msts(data[, i], seasonal.periods=c(24,168))` and `result$id <- names(data)[i]`?